# How do I show a "dojox / layout / FloatingPane" on a "dijit / layout / BorderContainer"

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using Dojo Toolkit 1.12. How can I show a `dojox/layout/FloatingPane` that moves on a `dijit/layout/BorderContainer`. The problem is that I do not know where `srcNodeRef` to locate it so that it can move across the screen. Thank you.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>`
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <!-- Estilos -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.2/dojo/resources/dojo.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.2/dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css"  media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.2/dojox/layout/resources/ResizeHandle.css"  media="screen">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
        body, html {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;}
    </style>
    <!-- Libraries -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.2/dojo/dojo.js">
    </script>
    <!-- Dojo -->        
    <script>
        require([
                "dijit/registry",
                "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
                "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
                "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
                "dojox/layout/FloatingPane",
               "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(
                registry,
                BorderContainer,
                TabContainer,
                ContentPane,
                FloatingPane) {
           //........................................................
           var border = new BorderContainer({
               design: "headline",
               style: "width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: yellow;",
               design: "headline",
               liveSplitters: true,
               gutters: true
           }, "divBody");
           //........................................................
           border.addChild(
               new TabContainer({
                   region: "center",
                   id: "tabs",
                   tabPosition: "top"
               })
           );
           var tabs = registry.byId("tabs");
           tabs.addChild(
               new ContentPane({
                   content: "content Tab 1",
                   title: "Tab 1"
               })
           );
           tabs.addChild(
               new ContentPane({
                   content: "content Tab 2",
                   title: "Tab 2"
               })
           );
           //........................................................
           border.addChild(
               new ContentPane({
                   region: "top",
                   id: "top",
                   content: "HEADER"
               })
           );
           //........................................................
           border.addChild(
               new ContentPane({
                   region: "left",
                   id: "left", 
                   content: "LEFT",
                   splitter: true,
               })
           );
           //........................................................
           border.addChild(
               new ContentPane({
                   region: "bottom",
                   id: "footer",
                   content: "FOOTER",
                   splitter: false
               })
           );
           //........................................................
           border.startup();
           //........................................................
           var floating = new FloatingPane({
               id: "floating",
               title: "A floating pane",
               resizable: true,
               dockable: true,
               style: "position:absolute; top:0; left:0;width:100px; height:100px;"
           });
           floating.addChild(
               new ContentPane({
                   content: "FLOATING"
               })
           );
           floating.startup();
           //........................................................
       });
    </script>        
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="divBody"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what have you done and also post the code

Comment: When defining the "new FloatingPane ({...}, ????)" I do not know where to place it so it floats on the screen.

Comment: Sorry if I got you wrong. Why do you want to place it at some location? Don't you want it to float?

Comment: Yes of course. My problem is that I do not know how to put content dynamically and it appears.

Comment: As this is the code now does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this example

```
http://jsfiddle.net/icsteveoh/ADPZS/
```

FloatingPane has a property 'content' to set whatever the content you need. In this example, content is set as part of declaration i.e. while creating the FloatingPane. If you want to set content dynamically, you can use

```
dijit.byId('yourfloatingpaneid').set('content',"Hello again");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It stays and works. Thank you.

    var floating = new FloatingPane({
        title: "A floating pane",
        resizable: true,
        dockable: true,
        style: "position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; width: 100px; height: 100px;"
    }, DomConstruct.create("div", null, dojo.body()));
    floating.addChild(
        new ContentPane({
            content: "FLOATING"
        })
    );
    floating.startup();